# How I make notification system with jQuery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, database

I try to make  control my message. Then for each my message  like and comments control. Then insert to notification table.

Comment: Just a hint use SetInterval()

Comment: Just a hint, put yourself in our shoes and try to answer such a question.

Comment: Then show us your sql query? What you have tried so far to achieve it

Comment: Maybe you should try to elaborate a bit more on your task. This might help users here. But it will surely help yourself in understanding what you really want to do and what you will need to do to accomplish it.

Comment: i make a notification system like stack overflow's

Answer (score 1):

Work in small steps. First try it without AJAX.

- Make a form that posts a message.
- Save the message in the database
- Next time you visit the page, show all previous messages.
- Now, use AJAX for retrieving messages instead of the page loading.
- Now, use AJAX for the form posting instead of a page post.

Tell us what you can already do, and where you need help. Show us what you have, what you tried. We'll help you from there.